# Gradle (Android) - Assigning current build variant to a gradle property

Tags: android, gradle

I have run into an issue where I would like to filter by build variant in a file that is not app/build.gradle.

Initally, I tried defining a function that would return all variants to start with:

```
def getApplicationVariant() {
   return android.libraryVariants.all
}
```

However, this returns an empty array.

I then considered an approach that saves the current buildVariant to a gradle property and then access that property later.

However upon browsing through gradle's documentation, I am unsure if this is feasible in the first place, as I've only come across properties that are set statically, prior to running a build.

There are quite a few posts that indicate how to achieve this is app/build.gradle. Some direction here would be most appreciated.

Comment: is this in a Gradle Plugin or in your regular app code?

Comment: In a library's build file, apologies I should have added that.